# Advantage of 'with' queries over plain 'select' and joins?

Tags: postgresql, performance, cte

Are there any advantages using `WITH` queries instead of simple `SELECT` queries using `JOIN`s performance wise?

I am asking solely about reading data (from catalogues specifically).

Comment: Sometimes a CTE will make things slower, sometimes it will make it faster

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As I already suspected, my question seems to be too unspecific / broad. I can provide some more specific example regarding a query I saw from a colleagues code querying the ANSI information schema about column definitions (`DEFAULT` and sequences specifically) tomorrow. I am more used to get the information from the native `pg_cataolg` and build up queries as neccesary from there. I have no clue how queries will be efficient using (the views(?) provided for the ANSI information schema) might impact the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres can treat queries in the with clause as optimization fences. Meaning that an expensive subquery will not necessarily be recomputed twice when visited.
https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/

Comment: That sounds promising, THX for your answer.